# Django 4 Logout Show error after pressing Logout Button

Tags: django-4.1

Got the error on pressing Logout Button-

```
@login_required
def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_login:login'))
```

error :ValueError at /accounts/logout/
The view django.contrib.auth.logout didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.